# How to Calculate Modular Multiplicative Inverse Groups

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I found this pairing property that exists with modular multiplicative inverses and I have questions surrounding it, but before I explain it I must first state that I use my own notation for modular multiplicative inverses. The notation is:

mi(x, y) = z. the mi is the abbreviation for the term multiplicative inverse. So for example if r = 467 and s = 521 then t, the multiplicative inverse of 13, is 193.

Using only odd positive integers, there is a pairing relationship between two rs. Lets have

mi(fa, f2) = y,  and another mi(fb, f2)  = z, where fb is not equal to y.

Putting in some numbers, we can have:
mi(13, 521)  = 481 [13 is our fa], and    ---- this is line A
mi(441, 521) = 267 [441 is our fb]        ---- this is line B

From both Line A and B respectively we can compute the gap between lower and higher factor, that is f2 - fa from line A and f2 - fb from line B. We will use this 'gap' value in the following two absolute value calculations:

From line A:
ABS (absolute value) of: mi(13, 521) - mi(521-13, 521) = 441 , and pairwise

From line B:
ABS (absolute value) of: mi(441, 521) - mi(521-441, 521) = 13,

Thus 13 and 441 form a pair because they can compute each other.

Working with the divisor 521 (this is our f2) this pairwise relationship holds for almost all odd positive integers from 1 to 519 inclusive. The two exceptions are 1 and 249.

If you take 249 and compute:
ABS (absolute value) of: mi(249, 521) - mi(521-249, 521) = 249. You can either say that there is no pair or that it pairs with itself.

Also note that even-odd parity is maintained in the pairings.

Now to explain the Groups:

To understand the groups that I want to explain, you have to have a different understanding of modular multiplicative inverses that is derived from the number line.

On the number line modular multiplicative inverses exist as consecutive multiples of two different positive integers that are co-prime. I will explain with an example.
let a = 467 and b = 521.  a x b = n (467 x 521 = 243307). The rounded up mid point (RU mid pt) of n = 243307 is: (243307 + 1) / 2 = 121654.

Though I don't know of any proof, the following relationship holds true numbers that are the product of 2 odd positive integers, which can either be prime factors or composites:

On the number line there always exists a number p such that if p is a multiple of a then p-1 is a multiple of b or vice versa. In our present example p = 76588.
In other words, 76588 is perfectly divisible by 467 (our a) and (76588-1 = 76587) is perfectly divisible by 521 (our b).

Computing mi(467, 521) we get 164. Now take p = 76588 and divide by 467. The answer is 164.
So now you know where multiplicative inverses originate from on the number line.
The multiplicative inverse value is actually the quotient of p divided by a, but not always, as will be explained below.

What I haven't found in math literature concerning modular multiplicative inverses is that the line p is symmetrical to another line q. Both p and q are bi-laterally symmetrical around the RU mid pt of n.

to get to q we compute [( (p-1) x (p-2) ) / 2] mod n, which in our example comes to: [(76587 x 76586) / 2] mod 243307 = 2932745991 mod 243307 = 166720.

The bi-lateral symmetry is that RU mid pt of n - p = q - RU mid pt of n
or,

121654 - 76588 = 166720 - 121654

at line q = 166720 you will discover that 166720 is divisible by 521 (our b) and q-1 = 166719 is divisible by 467 (our a).

For any odd positive integer that has a modular multiplicative inverse then p and q will exist.

For some numbers, p is divisible by a (as is the case with our example n of 243307) while with other numbers, say 723253, which 787 x 919, p is perfectly divisible by b (or p = 290404 is perfectly divisible by 919) and p-1 is perfectly divisible by 787.

when p is divisible by b then the multiplicative inverse mi(a, b) is the quotient at line q.

So mi(787, 919) = 550.  550 x 787 = 432850 which beyond the RU mid pt of 723253. Thus the the mi is now the quotient at line q and not line p, which was the case with n=243307.

So for any n, provided they are the product of 2 odd positive integers that are co-prime there is always a quotient before RU mid pt  of n (q1) and one after RU mid pt of n (q2).
With n=243307. q1 = 164 and q2 = 357.

Note the following correlation:
Remember above I said that
ABS (absolute value) of: mi(13, 521) - mi(521-13, 521) = 441
and that
ABS (absolute value) of: mi(441, 521) - mi(521-441, 521) = 13,

The above formula equates to q2 - q1 for each line A and B respectively.
Its just another understanding of this pairwise relationship.

I needed to explain all that to explain modular multiplicative inverse groups and then I will state my questions.

The only groups that I know of concerning modular multiplicative inverses follows from the pairwise relationship based on the value that is found from the following calculations:

1. find the RU mid pt of n = (fa x f2) and also for n = (fb x f2).
   in the above example:
   ((13 x 521) + 1) / 2 = 3387, and

((441 x 521) + 1) / 2 = 114881

2. Then find p

In the above example:

1. mi(fa, f2) x fa = 481 x 13 = 6253
   but 6253 is beyond the RU mid pt of n = 13 x 521 = 6773. Thus mi of 481 is actually q2 which is at line q. We want line p.
   p = ((6252 x 6251) / 2) mod (13 x 521) = 521
2. mi(fb, f2) x fb = 267 x 441 = 117747.
   Here too 117747 is beyond the RU mid pt of n = 441 x 521 = 229761. Thus mi of 441 is actually q2 which is at line q. we want line p.
   p = ((117746 x 117745) / 2) mod (441 x 521) = 112015
3. Subtract p from RU mid pt of n

In the above example,

from Line A:
3387 - 521 = 2866

and,

from Line B:
114881 - 112015 = 2866

All Modular Multiplicative inverse pairs have this property of the same value for: RU mid pt of n - p.

The group structure is found when I compute other modular multiplicative inverse pairs. Using the divisor 521 there are 8 other numbers that form a group with 13 and 441. The full list is:
13
21
39
49
63
91
117
147
273
441

For all of these 10 numbers RU mid pt of n - p = 2866.

Notice that the paired integers 13 and 441 are first and last. This is not by chance. It is symmetrical.

Using 21, the second number in the group:
ABS of: mi(21, 521) - mi(521-21, 521) = 273 (this is the second last number before 441).
proving the pair, I compute:
ABS of: mi(273, 521) - mi(521-273, 521) = 21

In like fashion 39 pairs with 147, the third last number of the group, 49 pairs with 117, the fourth last number and 63, the fifth number, pairs with 91 the 6th number (or 5th last number).

My questions are as follows:
How to calculate all the integers belonging to a group?

Except when an odd integer pairs with itself, every odd number below the divisor will form a pair with another odd number below the divisor. That pair is a group. In some cases the group may be limited to those two numbers but in other cases, as was shown with common difference of 2866, the group may have more than 2 numbers.
How many numbers will a particular group have? The group of '2866' has 10 numbers. Another group may have 4 but how can I calculate this instead of searching for it?

Comment: I don't understand your notation $\text{mi}(x,y)=z$. Is it equivalent to $xz\equiv_y 1$?